# SQL Server pair column pivot

Tags: sql-server

> I am using SQL server 2014. I required the following report. HeadName
>   is dynamic that can be any name if HeadType is  earning then show
>   Tot_hrs and Amount, if HeadType  is the deduction, then show the only
>   Amount.
>
> Note: make sure that HeadName Data should not be  hardcoded in the
>   query because the user can add data in earning and deduction for .eg
>   holiday work OT,  incentive, Late deduction, Loan etc
>
> I will provide two i.e fromPayslipDate and  ToPayslipDate result
>   should be displayed as the picture below.

```
CREATE TABLE #PaySlip (PaySlipID int, SlipNo varchar(50), SlipDate date, EmployeeID int, RatePerHrs numeric(18,2));
CREATE TABLE #PaySlipD (PaySlipID int,HeadType varchar(50),OrderNo int, HeadName varchar(50), Tot_hrs numeric(18,2), Amount numeric(18,2));


INSERT INTO #PaySlip
    (PaySlipID,SlipNo,SlipDate ,EmployeeID,RatePerHrs)
    values
    (3, '2018-0001',    '2018-10-03',   30, 7.00),
    (4, '2018-0002',    '2018-10-03',   23, 8.00);

INSERT INTO #PaySlipD
    (PaySlipID,HeadType,OrderNo,HeadName,Tot_hrs,Amount)
    values
(   3   ,   'Earning'   ,   2   ,   'Normal Hours'  ,   82  ,   574 ),
(   3   ,   'Earning'   ,   2   ,   'OT Normal'     ,   13.57   ,   0   ),
(   3   ,   'Earning'   ,   3   ,   'OT Holiday'    ,   0   ,   0   ),
(   3   ,   'Earning'   ,   5   ,   'Incentive'     ,   0   ,   0   ),
(   3   ,   'Deduction' ,   1   ,   'Loan'          ,   0   ,   0   ),
(   3   ,   'Deduction' ,   2   ,   'Tax'           ,   0   ,   26.13   ),
(   3   ,   'Deduction' ,   3   ,   'Employee NPF'  ,   0   ,   34.44   ),
(   3   ,   'Deduction' ,   4   ,   'Employer NPF'  ,   0   ,   48.22   ),
(   4   ,   'Earning'   ,   1   ,   'Normal Hours'  ,   71.24   ,   498.68  ),
(   4   ,   'Earning'   ,   2   ,   'OT Normal'     ,   4.85    ,   0   ),
(   4   ,   'Earning'   ,   3   ,   'OT Holiday'    ,   0   ,   0   ),
(   4   ,   'Earning'   ,   5   ,   'Incentive'     ,   0   ,   0   ),
(   4   ,   'Deduction' ,   1   ,   'Loan'          ,   0   ,   0   ),
(   4   ,   'Deduction' ,   2   ,   'Tax'           ,   0   ,   15.25   ),
(   4   ,   'Deduction' ,   3   ,   'Employee NPF'  ,   0   ,   29.92   ),
(   4   ,   'Deduction' ,   4   ,   'Employer NPF'  ,   0   ,   41.89   )
drop table #PaySlip
drop table #PaySlipD
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume HeadNames for 'Earning' HeadType is static. If yes this following script can help you. (I also put EmployeeId to cover more than one records)

```
drop table #PaySlip;
drop table #PaySlipD;
CREATE TABLE #PaySlip (PaySlipID int, SlipNo varchar(50), SlipDate date, EmployeeID int, RatePerHrs numeric(18,2));
CREATE TABLE #PaySlipD (PaySlipID int,HeadType varchar(50),OrderNo int, HeadName varchar(50), Tot_hrs numeric(18,2), Amount numeric(18,2));


INSERT INTO #PaySlip
    (PaySlipID,SlipNo,SlipDate ,EmployeeID,RatePerHrs)
    values
    (3, '2018-0001',    '2018-10-03',   30, 7.00),
    (4, '2018-0002',    '2018-10-03',   23, 8.00);

INSERT INTO #PaySlipD
    (PaySlipID,HeadType,OrderNo,HeadName,Tot_hrs,Amount)
    values
(   3   ,   'Earning'   ,   2   ,   'Normal Hours'  ,   82  ,   574 ),
(   3   ,   'Earning'   ,   2   ,   'OT Normal'     ,   13.57   ,   0   ),
(   3   ,   'Earning'   ,   3   ,   'OT Holiday'    ,   0   ,   0   ),
(   3   ,   'Earning'   ,   5   ,   'Incentive'     ,   0   ,   0   ),
(   3   ,   'Deduction' ,   1   ,   'Loan'          ,   0   ,   0   ),
(   3   ,   'Deduction' ,   2   ,   'Tax'           ,   0   ,   26.13   ),
(   3   ,   'Deduction' ,   3   ,   'Employee NPF'  ,   0   ,   34.44   ),
(   3   ,   'Deduction' ,   4   ,   'Employer NPF'  ,   0   ,   48.22   ),
(   4   ,   'Earning'   ,   1   ,   'Normal Hours'  ,   71.24   ,   498.68  ),
(   4   ,   'Earning'   ,   2   ,   'OT Normal'     ,   4.85    ,   0   ),
(   4   ,   'Earning'   ,   3   ,   'OT Holiday'    ,   0   ,   0   ),
(   4   ,   'Earning'   ,   5   ,   'Incentive'     ,   0   ,   0   ),
(   4   ,   'Deduction' ,   1   ,   'Loan'          ,   0   ,   0   ),
(   4   ,   'Deduction' ,   2   ,   'Tax'           ,   0   ,   15.25   ),
(   4   ,   'Deduction' ,   3   ,   'Employee NPF'  ,   0   ,   29.92   ),
(   4   ,   'Deduction' ,   4   ,   'Employer NPF'  ,   0   ,   41.89   )

    DECLARE @ColumnsEarning     VARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @ColumnsEarningWithHoursAlias       VARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @ColumnsEarningWithAmountAlias      VARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @ColumnsDeduction    VARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @SQLString  VARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @ColumnsEarning=STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(HeadName) 
                    from #PaySlipD  WHERE HeadType='Earning'
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

    --I put alias to understand which one related Hours which one Amount
        SET @ColumnsEarningWithHoursAlias=STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(HeadName) +' '+QUOTENAME(HeadName+'_Hours')
                        from #PaySlipD  WHERE HeadType='Earning'
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
            ,1,1,'');

        SET @ColumnsEarningWithAmountAlias=REPLACE(@ColumnsEarningWithHoursAlias,'_Hours','_Amount')

    SET @ColumnsDeduction=STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(HeadName) 
                    from #PaySlipD  WHERE HeadType='Deduction'
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');
PRINT(@ColumnsEarning)
PRINT(@ColumnsEarningWithHoursAlias)
PRINT(@ColumnsEarningWithAmountAlias)


SET @SQLString='
SELECT * FROM #PaySlip P
LEFT JOIN 
    (
    SELECT PaySlipId,'+@ColumnsEarningWithHoursAlias+' FROM 
        ( SELECT T.PaySlipId,HeadName,Tot_hrs FROM #PaySlipD T
        WHERE HeadType=''Earning''
        ) S
        PIVOT
        (
          sum(Tot_hrs)
          for HeadName in ('+@ColumnsEarning+')
        ) AS EH
    ) AS EH ON P.PaySlipId=EH.PaySlipId
LEFT JOIN 
    (
    SELECT PaySlipId,'+@ColumnsEarningWithAmountAlias+' FROM 
        ( SELECT T.PaySlipId,HeadName,Amount FROM #PaySlipD T
        WHERE HeadType=''Earning''
        ) S
        PIVOT
        (
          sum(Amount)
          for HeadName in ('+@ColumnsEarning+')
        ) AS EA
    ) AS EA ON EH.PaySlipId = EA.PaySlipId
LEFT JOIN 
    (
    SELECT * FROM 
        ( SELECT T.PaySlipId,HeadName,Amount FROM #PaySlipD T
        WHERE HeadType=''Deduction''
        ) S
        PIVOT
        (
          sum(Amount)
          for HeadName in ('+@ColumnsDeduction+')
        ) AS D
    ) AS D ON EH.PaySlipId = D.PaySlipId

    ';

EXEC(@SQLString)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but  HeadName is dynamic user can add, modify & delete the data, so we can't hardcoded the Name. for e.g, if I add in earning Holiday work then it is not showing that data

Comment: Hi @naweez, I have updated the script. Now it is fully dynamic. I also put Alias to Earning columns to understand which one related with Hours, which one Amount.

Comment: thanks for the reply. now I modified actual data, please read it again.

Comment: Hi @naweez I have updated the script.

Comment: Hi @Zeki Gumus, it's working fi9 only problem coming when adding some head name so it not showing sequentially. if i want filter employee ID and Payslip date range where we can e.g employee = 1 and Slipdate between 2018-01-01 and 2018-01-31.